# ubuntu 16.04 reinstall all drivers

Tags: drivers, package-management, sound, bluetooth

I have no idea why, but I think some of my drivers are gone.  Is there a way to reinstall all unknown drivers? I found some posts about re-installing all packages but what if I don't have the packages anymore? (I do not even know) So even if I tried their steps to reinstall all packages, I might not have all drivers needed right?

Somehow my bluetooth isn't working, I cannot detect anything.  Checked it, status is inactive.  In my sound option, there used to be a few sound cards I am able to choose from, but somehow it says `Dummy Output` now.  In additional drivers, there's only my video card driver and one unknown driver which I don't even know what it is for.

Thanks in advance for any help and tips.

Comment: Try disabling Secure Boot at UEFI first. Then, if the problem persists, I suggest you [edit] the question and provide a lot more info, namely hardware specs.

Comment: @MichaelBay it's already disabled.  Where can I get a list of the hardware specs though?

Comment: You could use GRUB to boot into an older kernel or try `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` and then reboot

Comment: @Jeremy31 thx thx thx! this did help. Do you want to post this as an answer so I can give you a check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes during an update the linux-image-extra fails to update, so you can use the Grub menu at boot to select Advanced options or Previous Linux versions to boot into an older kernel.

An alternative is to attempt `sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)` while in the bad kernel and reboot.

The linux-image-extra package contains all wireless and bluetooth kernel modules along with a lot of others