# How do I revert to ALSA?

Tags: 16.04, sound, alsa, oss

I wanted to try out `oss` because sound on `alsa` is not great. I am on Ubuntu 16.04.

Anyway I installed `alsa-oss` using

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-oss
```

but it didn't recognize my sound card (it's `Realtek ac290`). So I uninstalled it and now I don't have any sound. I have tried reinstalling `alsa` using

```
 sudo aptitude --purge reinstall linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils linux-image-`uname -r` linux-ubuntu-modules-`uname -r` libasound2
```

but this doesn't fix anything, still no sound.
When I type `alsamixer` in terminal I get:

```
cannot open mixer: No such file or directory
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)
```

This command installed all the missing drivers and fixed the problem.

Source: [ubuntu 16.04 reinstall all drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940091/ubuntu-16-04-reinstall-all-drivers)